# Un-indenting code when copy-and-pasting from an external editor

Tags: feature-request, indentation

Sometimes, when I copy and paste code from my editor to the question box, the indent level is too much; I think there should be buttons to move the indent level left or right without having to unindent the code in a text editor first.

Comment: +1.  If every line pasted contains 4+ spaces or 2+ tabs, it should be safe to assume that it is code, and to rewrite the whitespace accordingly.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠWon't see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just highlight and press <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd>

For example:

```
    echo json_encode(array(
            'success' => $s,
            'fee_id' => $e,
            'id' => $i,
            'randomness' => array($e, $_POST, $query),
            'error' => $error,
        ));

    exit();
```

<kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd>

```
echo json_encode(array(
        'success' => $s,
        'fee_id' => $e,
        'id' => $i,
        'randomness' => array($e, $_POST, $query),
        'error' => $error,
    ));

exit();
```

<kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd>

echo json_encode(array(
        'success' => $s,
        'fee_id' => $e,
        'id' => $i,
        'randomness' => array($e, $_POST, $query),
        'error' => $error,
    ));
exit();

*Well thats gibberish...*

And when you press <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd> again it should go back to the 2nd example above of being formatted nicely :-)

Comment: This doesn't always work as expeected.  Also, not pressing ctrl-k is always better than pressing it ten times to fix your indents.

Comment: @Wont The OP specifically asked for buttons to do it, not a magic auto-indenter like you seem to want